# How to use multiple layouts inside the same controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I wanted to ask how can I define a multiple layouts for the same controller in Laravel. 
The scenario here is like the following:

I have a controller Home and i have two actions in this controller one called steps and the other called login.

I want the both of them load different layout.

The way that I used to make this is as follow:

```php
protected $layout = "layouts.page";

public function index()
{
    // Get to the page of the website making steps
    $this->layout->content = View::make('steps');
}
```

Can I define multiple layouts? Maybe passing an array as follow:

```php
protected $layout = array('first' => "layouts.page", 'second' => 'layouts.second');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [View Composers](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers) or look at the section passing sub-views to views under http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views.

You can also specify multiple sections for the layout that is defined at http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating

**EDIT:**

If you want to define a master layout for different views from the same controller, then define the layout on the View it self. Take a look at the section [Using A Blade Layout](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating)

The `@extends` is used to define the layout on the view itself.

Hope this helps for what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you clarify in detail what you mean by mutliple layouts, from the question above it looks like you want multiple master Layouts. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, 
i want multiple master layouts

Comment: What is the scenario that you will require multiple layouts for a single view?

Comment: i want to make an action for the home controller called `steps` that has a layout and another layout for the user to login in the same home controller , does it a good practice ?

Comment: You can use `@extends` to do that directly on the view. Why define it at the controller. It is not a good practice to define the layouts on the Controller. Keeping the Views dependent on Controllers only for its data is a better practice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35268/discussion-between-abishek-r-srikaanth-and-osos)

Answer (score 3):

Best solution is to create a method to generate your view, nesting your multiples layouts :

```
return View::make('layouts.master', array())
       ->nest('section_one', YOUR_SECOND_MASTER, array())
       ->nest...
```

and stop setting `protected $layout` with a layout.

Answer (score 3):

I achieve in this way

```
$this->layout = View::make('layout.master');
$this->layout->content = View::make('step.demo')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [BaseController](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/controllers/BaseController.php), which your controller likely extends, you'll see the layout variable is ultimately used simply as th e result of any old View.

In other words, your `$layout` variable is just a View. You can create any `$layout` variable in your controller:

```
<?php

class MyController extends BaseController {

    protected $layout;

    protected $layout_alt;

    // Here we're over-riding setupLayout() from
    // the BaseController
    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }

        if ( ! is_null($this->layout_alt))
        {
            $this->layout_alt = View::make($this->layout_alt);
        }

    }

}
```

Then in your view, you can return:

```
 $this->layout_alt->content = View::make('steps');
```

Of course, the possibilities are endless as Abishek R Srikaanth pointed out. You can do fancy things with Blade as well :D

Answer (score 1):

The way i do this is quite similar to @fideloper's answer.

```
protected $layout;
private $_layout = null;

public function __construct()
{

}

private function _setupLayout()
{
    if ( ! is_null($this->_layout))
    {
        $this->layout = View::make($this->_layout);
    }
}

public function home() {
    $this->_layout = 'layouts.1col_public';
    $this->_setUpLayout();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('static/home');
}

public function about() {
    $this->_layout = 'layouts.2col_public';
    $this->_setUpLayout();
    $this->layout->active_menu = 'about';
    $this->layout->content = View::make('static/default');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't common practise, and I haven't tested it yet, but it's worth a try.

In your controller's method:

```
$this->layout = View::make('layouts.master1");
```